# Sending voicemail to group of numbers?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am just exploring voicemail at Twilio, and I thought that I can ask a related question here.
How would I send a voicemail to a group of numbers (as an effort of voice based marketing campaign)? what APIs will I need? and is there any related docs about it?

Shall we send an audio file? Or can we create the voice on Android or iPhone and send it using Android SDK or iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

You can call those numbers and play an audio file using the [Play](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/play) verb. To call a number, you can use our [REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api). Here's [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls) on how to do that in multiple programming languages.

Hope this helps you out, but come back here if you have any more questions.

Comment: You may want to look at Answering Maachine Detection (AMD) as well, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection. Make sure your efforts fall under TCPA guidelines or the equivalent in the dialed destination - https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-telephone-consumer-protection-act-tcpa.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I mean ringless voicemail drop service